# Screen goes white after state change React, Redux, Redux-Thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm having an issue with React. when I get data by calling an API, data comes back perfectly fine, it loads and displays in a table. On the other hand, when I tried to add data to the DB using the user interface, it works, the request returns 200, and the data is in the database, but after all is finished on the React end, the screen turns white. The proper route still shows up in the browser, yet the screen for that route turns blank after, what only seems to be POST actions. Here is my code.

component code to add an event to the DB

```
const AddEventModal = (props: any) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const onSubmit = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let eventData: Event = {
      eventName: event.target[1].value,
      location: event.target[2].value,
      eventDate: event.target[3].value,
      startTime: event.target[4].value,
      endTime: event.target[5].value,
    };

    dispatch(addingEventToDb);
    dispatch(addEventAsyncToDB(eventData));
    props.toggleShow = false;
  };

  return (
    <MDBModal
      show={props.basicModal}
      setShow={props.setBasicModal}
      tabIndex="-1"
    >
      ......tsx code
    </MDBModal>
  );
};
```

Here is what the Thunk looks like.

```
export const addEventAsyncToDB = (event:Event) => {
    return (dispatch:any) => {
        return addEvent(event).then(res => {
            dispatch(addedEventToDBAction(res?.data));
        })
    }
}
```

And here is the actual AJAX code thats being called

```
export const addEvent = async (event: Event) => {
    try{
        const res = await axios.post(`${baseURI}/Events`, event);
        return res;
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reduce the amount of code to a *minimal* reproducible example?  That would help with identifying the issue.

Comment: @possum just changed it for you

Comment: "The screen turns white" normally means that there has been an error while rendering components, and React has crashed.  Is there an error in the console?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @markerikson this is the error I get:: Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function

Comment: @markerikson Im using AG grid for react and this is an error I get as well when the screen turns white:: Uncaught TypeError: rowData.map is not a function

Comment: That error is telling you that whatever data is being used is not actually an array.  If it's coming from inside the grid library, then you should check what data you're passing in.